# change the attribute value on blur for text boxes

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have multiple textboxes and I want to update a data-price attribute on blur.
If I change the value need to change specific  'data-price' attribute.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#price').blur(function(){
    $test=$(this).attr('data-price');
      $test=$(this).val();
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="price" class="default used_asset1" maxlength="8" placeholder="Amount" data-price="342" name="price" type="text" value="342">
<input id="price" class="default used_asset1" maxlength="8" placeholder="Amount" data-price="3" name="price" type="text" value="3">
<input id="price" class="default used_asset1" maxlength="8" placeholder="Amount" data-price="25" name="price" type="text" value="25">
<input id="price" class="default used_asset1" maxlength="8" placeholder="Amount" data-price="32" name="price" type="text" value="32">
```

Is it possible to update attribute value in jquery.What I did wrong in my code

Comment: You're using duplicate ID's which is the first problem. What exactly would you want to change/add when blur is fired?

Comment: want to change the data-price for specific textbox

Comment: This what you were looking for? https://jsfiddle.net/5n71z2uq/

Comment: Use `console.log(test);` to see your values, `$test` is not a proper variable for jQuery it is `var test`, `$test` worked but it was intermittent when reporting. Lastly `id` is a unique identifier, so use `price` as a `class attribute` or use html type `input`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `price` as class because element IDs should be unique within the entire document.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.price').blur(function(){
    //$test=$(this).attr('data-price');
      //$test=$(this).val();
      $(this).attr('data-price', $(this).val());
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input class="price efault used_asset1" maxlength="8" placeholder="Amount" data-price="342" name="price" type="text" value="342">
<input class="price efault used_asset1" maxlength="8" placeholder="Amount" data-price="3" name="price" type="text" value="3">
<input class="price efault used_asset1" maxlength="8" placeholder="Amount" data-price="25" name="price" type="text" value="25">
<input class="price efault used_asset1" maxlength="8" placeholder="Amount" data-price="32" name="price" type="text" value="32">
```

Comment: @user3386779 welcome my friend, happy to help you :)

Answer (score 0):

You can't select an element by ID if the ID has been duplicated. It will work on the first one and ignore the rest. Selecting by class or element name will select all of them.

https://jsfiddle.net/5n71z2uq/

I'm selecting the inputs but you can put a class in and select VIA class.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('input').blur(function(){
    $(this).attr('data-price', this.value);
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Yeah you can. It's very easy, just try it.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#price').blur(function(){
   $(this).data('price', $(this).val());
  });
});
```